# Problem with converting from bitmap to ImageBitmap in c#

Tags: c#, image

When I convert two pixels bitmap to imagebitmap I change it to common image with many pixcels and chenging the to the gradiend (black and white pixel are now gradient from black throught grey to white)

```
public static BitmapImage Bitmap2BitmapImage(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
        memory.Position = 0;

        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        bitmapImage.Freeze();

        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Do you want the generated BitmapImage to also be 2 pixels wide? If yes, you can set the DecodePixelWidth/DecodePixelHeight properties on bitmapImage.

Comment: I don't need 2 pixels image, when i'm creating two pixels bitmap, one pixel black second white, then i'm converting it to imagebitmap and i want to get image half black half white, but i get color gradient from black to white (you know the border is not clear ,the color changing from one to another smoothly)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381012/how-can-i-stretch-bitmap-in-wpf-without-smoothing-pixels

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  Go back to the code that generated the Bitmap object.  The Graphics.InterpolationMode and Graphics.PixelOffsetMode properties that were used to generate it are a very big deal on very small bitmaps that are blown up to larger sizes.  Perhaps Graphics.SmoothingMode, hard to tell with nothing to look at.

Comment: So how to turn off the SmoothingMode in BitmapImage?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Here is a method which can scale a `Bitmap` without smoothing.

```
        public static Bitmap Scale(int count, Bitmap source)
    {
        if (count <= 0) { return source; }
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(source.Size.Width * count, source.Size.Height * count);
        var sourcedata = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), source.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bitmapdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), bitmap.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        unsafe
        {
            var srcByte = (byte*)sourcedata.Scan0.ToPointer();
            var dstByte = (byte*)bitmapdata.Scan0.ToPointer();
            for (var y = 0; y < bitmapdata.Height; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x < bitmapdata.Width; x++) {
                    long index = (x / count) * 4 + (y / count) * sourcedata.Stride;
                    dstByte[0] = srcByte[index];
                    dstByte[1] = srcByte[index + 1];
                    dstByte[2] = srcByte[index + 2];
                    dstByte[3] = srcByte[index + 3];
                    dstByte += 4;
                }
            }
        }
        source.UnlockBits(sourcedata);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapdata);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

In this situation, you can get the correct `BitmapSource` with:

```
   var bitmapSrc = MyImagingHelper.Scale(100,twoPixelBitmap)//this will get a Bitmap size 200 * 100,change the ratio if it is not enough
   .ToBitmapSource();//Convert to bitmap source
```

---

if you just want to covert a `Bitmap` into `BitmapSource` to show in WPF Controls, try this method:

```
    [DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    public static extern bool DeleteHBitmap(IntPtr hObject);        


    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this Bitmap target)
    {
        var hbitmap = target.GetHbitmap();
        try {
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally {
            DeleteHBitmap(hbitmap);
        }
    }
```

Don't ignore the DeleteHBitmap call!

Comment: Updated, you must scale the bitmap before converting it to BitmapSource

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap getRandomTwo()
        {
            Bitmap alone = new Bitmap(1, 2);
            alone.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.White);
            alone.SetPixel(0, 1,Color.Black);
            return alone;
        }
```

this is the code to generate bitmap